# More than 10 years of experience or over 10 years of experience

Tags: word-usage

Would you please suggest the best translation between the following:

> 1. More than 10 years of experience as Senior Technical Architect
> 2. Over 10 years of experience as Senior Technical Architect

The sentence is in the description of the skills of a Technical profile.

Comment: These mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: "... as _a_ Senior Technical Architect"

Answer (score 19):

As far as a resume is concerned, no difference whatsoever. In this context, both mean the same.

[Cambridge:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over)

> A2: *over (preposition)* = more than

And so in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/over)

> *over* = Higher or more than (a specified number or quantity)

Answer (score 5):

If you're speaking this then I'd recommend using over 20 years, rather than more than 10 years.

On the other hand, if you're writing it, then you could say '10+ years of experience.'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed, *over 20 years* is definitely better than just *more than 10 years* 

Answer (score 5):

As Maulik stated, there's no difference in this context. You may be interested to know, however, that until 2014, the AP style guide, which is the Bible of American journalists, would have said you had to use "more than" in this instance.

It upset a lot of people when they took this rule out of AP style (you can find a lot of news stories about it, like [this one](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/compost/wp/2014/03/26/for-the-ap-stylebook-its-more-than-over/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.3483c2ffea5e)), and I am guessing there are a whole lot of professional editors out there who loved this rule and might still insist on changing "over" to "more than" if you wrote it that way.

Comment: I'm not a professional journalist, but I am a native English speaker from America, and I have to say I still prefer "more than" for stuff like this. "Over" is still perfectly clear and I wouldn't think ill of someone for using it here, but it just feels...vaguely wrong and I don't know why. Maybe it is for the same reasons the AP used to recommend against it? Like "over a year" or "over a ton" feel fine, but "over five years" or "over 30 pages" are both weird: I don't expect a number there.

Comment: @amalloy I don't disagree. One of my first bosses had adopted this rule, and I found I liked it, too, and I spent a lot of years being one of those editors who would usually change it. So, it's still my personal preference and how I would write it myself. I try not to edit other people's writing that way, anymore, though. There are some situations where I do think it improves clarity, though.

Comment: I think the issue is (was) one of ambiguity.  "Over" could mean "more than" or "above" or "across" or "throughout" depending on context.

Comment: @Timbo Indeed. What amalloy said is actually a good example. Does "over a year" mean "more than one year" or does it mean "over the course of a single year"? I could also say "I searched over 30 pages of text for examples." It's not clear if that means "more than 30 pages" or if "searched over" is being used as a phrasal verb, and it means I thoroughly searched exactly 30 pages.